# How to implement Grid view in all iOS versions?

Tags: swiftui

I want to implement Grid View in my app and I am using swiftui. Since LazyVGrid is available on devices running iOS 14 and later I somehow implemented the grid view. I need two columns from the code below. But the last element sticks to the left, I cannot figure out how to give the proper padding. If someone has implemented Grid view that runs on all iOS versions then any help would would be highly appreciated.

```
import SwiftUI

struct NewViewPracc: View {
    var tempList: [String] = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
          
            Text("Hacking with Swift")
                .padding()
                .background(Color.red)
                .cornerRadius(16)
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 32)
                        .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 4)
                )
            
            ScrollView {
                VStack(spacing: 4) {
                    ForEach(0..<((tempList.count + 1) / 2), id: \.self) { rowIndex in
                        HStack(spacing: 16) {
                            ForEach(0..<2) { columnIndex in
                                let index = rowIndex * 2 + columnIndex

                                if index < tempList.count {
                                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
                                

                                        Text("Header")
                                            .foregroundColor(Color.cyan)
                                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                                        
                                        Text("Title")
                          
                                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                                        Text("sub title")
                         
                                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                                    }
                                    .padding(.horizontal, 12)
                                    .padding(.top, 12)
                                    .padding(.bottom, 32)
                                    .frame(width: 171, height: 231, alignment: .topLeading)
                                    .background(Color.gray)
                                    .cornerRadius(16)

                                } else {
                                    Spacer()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 16, leading: 0, bottom: 16, trailing: 0))
            }

        }
    }
    
    var numberOfRows: Int {
        let itemCount = tempList.count
        let itemsPerRow = 2
        return itemCount % itemsPerRow != 0 ? itemCount / itemsPerRow + 1 : itemCount / itemsPerRow
    }
}

struct NewViewPracc_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NewViewPracc()
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The cell in the last row is being pushed to the left by the `Spacer`. All the cells have a fixed width of 171pt, so in the other rows, there will be space to the left and the right that you are not seeing. To fix the last row, apply the same width to the `Spacer`:

```swift
} else {
    Spacer()
        .frame(width: 171)
}
```

Alternatively, if you want all the cells to have equal width then you could apply `maxWidth: .infinity` to every cell, instead of a fixed width:

```swift
if index < tempList.count {
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
        // content as before
    }
    // padding and other modifiers as before
    .frame(height: 231, alignment: .topLeading)
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)

} else {
    Spacer()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
}
```